# The eigenfunctions of $H =\frac{p^2}{2m}+ V_0 \log(|x|/a)$ and a curious virial theorem result

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, virial-theorem

I'm thinking about applications of the virial theorem to $1d$ quantum systems. The statement of the virial theorem is that all bound states of the Hamiltonian $T+V$ satisfy the constraint
$$\langle 2 T \rangle = \langle x \frac{dV}{dx} \rangle$$
where $T=\frac{p^2}{2m}$ and $V$ are the kinetic and potential energies respectively.

There's something strange that happens for the case of $$H = \frac{p^2}{2m} + V_0 \log(|x|/a)$$ Here, I take $V_0>0$ to ensure that the eigenspectrum is discrete and bounded below.

Plugging in this potential into the virial theorem gives a constant kinetic energy! That is, we have

$$\langle T \rangle = \frac{V_0}{2}$$

---

I find this result surprising, as it says that all eigenstates of the Hamiltonian, even those varying widely in total energy, have the same kinetic energy. I'm hoping to gain intuition for this result and to understand what the result means for the shape of the eigenfunctions. What do the eigenfunctions of this Hamiltonian look like at low and high energy? In particular, does the constraint with the average kinetic energy being constant in total energy have a fingerprint in the shape of the wavefunctions?

Comment: Numerically looking at the eigenfunctions (https://i.imgur.com/zzvCkSM.png) it seems to be what you'd expect, a discrete spectrum with eigenfunctions decaying outside of the potential, and wiggling inside the potential. Not sure concretely what else there is to say

Comment: @QCD_IS_GOOD This is good to see - I agree that it looks like a generic set of bound states for a potential growing to infinity at large $|x|$. My hope had been that there would be something nice stemming from the constraint - for example, for potentials with both a bound and continuous spectrum (like $3d$ hydrogen), a virial theorem giving a (negative) proportionality between $\langle T \rangle$ and $E$ will show that the kinetic energy shrinks to zero as the total energy approaches zero from below. This then means that the wavefunction slope is increasingly flat as $E$ approaches zero.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\langle p^2 \rangle$ is constant, one would expect the distance between the nodes of the wave function would not show a strong dependence (if any) on the quantum number, which is shown in figure in the comments.

Comment: Could you explain this further? Naively, I would expect that the oscillations would have local wavenumber like $\sqrt{2m(E-V(x))}$ for large $E$ in a WKB-approximation, which would grow like the usual $\sqrt{2mE}$ at large $E$ for small $x$, so that the oscillations will become more and more rapid (and the distances between nodes smaller and smaller) at large $E$ close to the origin.

Comment: Classically, constant KE  ($T$) is constant p-squared is constant p. In QM p is d/dx, so with real wave function, that's (average) node spacing. Maybe they bunch up at small x per your point.

Comment: Thanks, I think you're correct about the average node spacing. I'm still not 100% following your reasoning, would you mind editing in some more details? As an aside, if I use WKB to estimate the node spacing as $\frac{1}{2 \pi x*} \frac{1}{\hbar}\int_{-x*}^{x*}dx \sqrt{E - V_0 \log(|x|/a)}$, barring any errors, I indeed get that this quantity is constant as a function of total energy $E$. However, the local density of nodes changes as a function of position.

Comment: Another aside, just so we're on the same page, if I applied the classical virial theorem to this problem, the classical virial theorem would just say that $T$ is approximately constant in $E$ when averaged over a period, not that $T$ is constant in time.

Comment: @user196574 I really don't know anymore..I was just winging it. Contrast with harmonic oscillator wave functions, which increase energy linearly and show shorter node spacing at the center, and larger amplitude at the extrema (which has a straightforward classical interpretation), and the infinite square well which are quadratic in energy with uniform node space for a given $n$...which also has a simple classical interpretation: constant $p$ bouncing back and forth.

Comment: No worries, it seems you're onto something. It looks like in many cases that the average distance between nodes within the oscillatory part goes like $\frac{h}{\sqrt{m T}}$. This should be directly seen via WKB, so I'll see if I can get this right.

Answer (score 1):

> There's something strange that happens for the case of $$H = \frac{p^2}{2m} + V_0 \log(|x|/a)$$ Here, I take $V_0>0$
> ...we have
> $$\langle T \rangle = \frac{V_0}{2}$$

> What do the eigenfunctions of this Hamiltonian look like at low and high energy?

[The link provided by QCD_IS_GOOD in the comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeHv9.png) shows what some eigenfunctions look like.

> ...does the constraint with the average kinetic energy being constant in total energy have a fingerprint in the shape of the wavefunctions?

The average kinetic energy being constant constrains the integral of the absolute value of the derivative of the wave function like this:
$$
\langle T\rangle = \int dx {\left|\frac{d\psi}{dx}\right|}^2 = V_0\;,
$$
where I have chosen units such that $m=\hbar=1$.

This tells you something about the shape of the wavefunction, but not a whole lot.

Comment: +1, and I agree that it currently seems like the constraint isn't telling us much. I'll wait and see if anyone notices a more direct fingerprint in the shape of the wavefunctions.